# Decrypt AES256 data that is encrpted in Java

Tags: apex, encryption

I have AES256 , base64 encrypted data:

```
C5j45mSEdqfz4f4GnrwR2T25tizY5gb3JoVNtWp8DiYOW5d+qvPx/ODmQIQqNXpZ1YkIjLwu5BAjDh3QmlrC4DKwTvbSrVqxh7OJdGDQy60ebp0o1cmLBCJuqzAOh2KAZC6L9v4wkwEb9dFOPesImY15DySPeyYiuLHL7n2dHmyVUMcDUrp9TAm85daCyG5mKhaAy2SP8iNBPoUBWSIDDEM7vG5Ganxu6JVzG4V6zGYQlLXAi33Ct9Fs99YE02KKR4kiw52eE1nS4hwReMZnP4vuU1FxM0BZfWAdUV8m9pQ=
```

And Decryption Key:

```
v3erqY/EGg1NI0yFHYLsMt7IuqJksxNjo1dlhsOo6Zs=
```

And the Decrypted output:

http://b2bfsta.edc.cingular.net:8180/b2bservlets/TCMLoginDispatch.dyn?loginChannel=EBM&uid=B2c18e47fbc6e94ec7e5a92dece2c2684a4e3421a&sourceSystemId=iPhone6-NewOrder&profileType=PLATINUM&peDealId=o31634600562&enableDDR=true

So the encryption is being done in java. I am unable to decrpyt in Apex !!!
I know the way we can do in Java:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] initialVector) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        return cipherText;
    }
```

But how to do the same in Apex?
 Please help me out .

Comment: What's going wrong with the decryption, any error or  is the output not what you're expecting ?